# Repeat a function for duration

Tags: python, function, timing, raspberry-pi

In python 3 how can you repeat a function for say 10 seconds. In this case the function is turning outputs on a raspberry pi high and low for specific amounts of time. This needs to happen for an amount of time specified prior to this happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def run_wrapper(sec):
    starttime = datetime.datetime.now()
    endtime = None
    while True:
        f()
        endtime = datetime.datetime.now()
        if (endtime - starttime).total_seconds() >= sec:
            break
    print('Ran for %s seconds' % (endtime - starttime).total_seconds())
```

where `f` is the function you want to call. Keep in mind that this doesn't run for **exactly**  `sec` seconds. It calls the function if `sec` seconds haven't passed. For example if your function takes, say 30 seconds, and you specify 31 seconds, your function will be called twice for a total of 60 seconds.

Comment: This will max the CPU out for the duration this function runs

Comment: No more than repeatedly calling the function.

Comment: True, I just thought it was worth mentioning. They could always add a `time.sleep()`  to slow things down a little if required

Comment: But, that means your function **will not** run for 10 seconds. I believe OP wants it to run for 10 seconds continuously

Comment: It depends on the exact requirements I guess, maybe once a second for 10 seconds would be fine. Either way it's a good solution that they can tailor to their specific needs

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the function to be continuously re-called throughout the duration of the time, then you could just do this:

```
import time
f()
time.sleep(sec)
g()
```

Here `f` is a function that causes some result that is undone by `g`; since `g` isn't called until after `sec` seconds have passed, the results of `f` will stay in effect for as long as you need.

Edit: if `f` takes a non-trivial amount of time and you need this to be more precise, try the following:

```
import time
before_f = time.clock()
f()
after_f = time.clock()
time.sleep(sec-(after_f-before_f))
g()
```